# Trying to import modules in js

Tags: javascript, module

i cannot run this code for somereason 
ive tried { ... }
and ive also tried calling it by './libs.js'

nothing seems to be working. here are the errors im getting.

(Im a beginner at js and i only understand basic concepts so far)

[main.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raXSX.png)

[new-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLEqt.png)

Comment: try to use `'./CalcMod'` in import statement. and also show the code of this file.

Comment: That didnt work. ill update the page with the source file

Comment: @AbdullahAziz Got any other tips i took a screenshot of the error.

Comment: still there is issue, please share your code from `lib.js` also. let me solve it now.

Comment: as it cannot find your `main.js` by the `loader.js`. I think your `node` and `npm` are not correctly installed. Can you check you node and npm version. and try to re-install.

Comment: @AbdullahAziz okay i uploaded a picture of lib.js

Comment: @AbdullahAziz my node version is v10 15.1 and npm is 6.9.0

Comment: great! I tried this and working fine here. check this link https://codesandbox.io/s/oxj6l5jyn9. and see console.

Comment: @AbdullahAziz i reinstalled node and i still got the same error. im not sure why it wont work

Comment: Now try one last thing. Make another directory somewhere else and create these two files and run from there after this command `npm install`

Comment: @AbdullahAziz okay i got a new error ill upload it.

Comment: @AbdullahAziz nevermind its still not working. should i factory reset my macbook?

Comment: Hold on, it is all good now. See my answer brother! I wish now you can fix this.

Comment: Please update me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

`import { ... } from './CalcMod'`

You have a "named" import, so it is looking for the file elsewhere, you instead need to import it like a file.

Comment: How would i go about importing it like a file?

Comment: its giving me an error. its still saying throw err;

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you're importing the files from the correct location - prepend with `./` and make sure the file is `.js`:

```
import { addition, subtract, multiply, divide } from "./CalcMod.js";
```

Comment: I attempted that, but it didnt work. i updated the image with the list of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! sometimes `loader` gives error when the directory is dirty and we could not figure it out why. Now your actual error is gone. This error you are showing me now is as expected because you are trying to run and execute new syntax and with `node` which does not support these features by default. Although it releases the experimental way of doing this. There are the steps.

- Create a new directory.
- In that directory create a file **lib.mjs** (Note: The extension is **.mjs**)
- Create another file **main.mjs**

### lib.mjs

```
export function subtract(num1, num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
  }

export function add(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

### main.mjs

```
import { add , subtract } from "./lib";

console.log(add(4, 5));
```

Lastly, run `main.mjs` with this command **`node --experimental-modules main.mjs`**

Boom! All works now.

[image]

Enjoy your day.